# Return error "historical backend error: out of gas" when calling a contract view method for a specified block number

Tags: web3js, history

To get the historical price of tokens, I'm calling a UniswapV3 pair contract for a specific block number with web3.js:

```
const slot0 = await pairContract.methods.slot0().call({}, 79094457);
```

If I am not specifying the block number (which here is 79094457), the call doesn't return any error. Also, I have this error on Optimism but not on other networks.

First of all, how could I be "out of gas" if I am calling a view, which doesn't require any gas? And second, how can I solve this?

Comment: views can cost gas: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/79804/7598

Answer (score 0):

My problem was indeed Optimism specific, because I was calling a block number (79094457) that was anterior to the bedrock update, and Alchemy RPCs (as well as multiple public RPCs I've tried) will throw this error for calls to block minted before bedrock.